# How to know which files (scripts and configurations) I have installed by apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I always use rpm --query --package-name to see what files (scripts and configurations) I have installed. I'm looking for the similar command in ubuntu. Is there any equivalent command for apt-get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `--package-name` option for `rpm`.  Perhaps you meant

`rpm -q -l`*package-name*

The analogous command for that would be

`dpkg -L`*package-name*

To list all packages

`dpkg -l`
   `rpm -qa`

and to identify a package based on a pathname

`dlocate`*pathname*
   `rpm -qf`*pathname*

Further reading:

- [rpm -- RPM Package Manager](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html)
- [dpkg - package manager for Debian](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html)
- [`dlocate(1)` program to view debian package information](http://manpages.org/dlocate)

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the list of files in `pkgname`, use

```
dpkg -L pkgname
```

For more details, see `man dpkg`.